# How to connect to a VPC on Google Cloud using VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm on my home network. I've installed a VPN server using Raspberry Pi. I've connected my laptop with 4G (using my phone). I had a different IP. After connecting to my VPN server I had my IP from home. So this seems to work.

But now I want to create a VPC on Google Cloud from which I can only connect from my home network.

I was looking to this [blog](https://www.cloudassessments.com/blog/extend-your-network-to-google-cloud-using-cloud-vpn/), but I'm not sure if this will work for me, or if this is the setup I need to follow? I want to connect to a fully private GKE network. (vpc)

My general goal is to create something like [here](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/creating-private-kubernetes-clusters-on-gke.html).

I want to deploy a fully private Kubernetes cluster in google cloud from which I can connect from home OR using my VPN to my home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Internal load balancer on Kubernetes engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) which is currently in beta to set this up. You have to create an internal load balancer by adding the LoadBalancer specification to service resource. This will eventually provide access outside the cluster using the internal load balancer ingress IP. As if you have VPN access to your GCP virtual private cloud (VPC) network, same VPC network used to create Kubernetes cluster should be able to access services through the K8 internal load balancer. More information is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing).

You may also find these links helpful [Link1](https://blog.mrtrustor.net/post/iptables-kubernetes/) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738500/google-container-engine-and-vpn).